# regex to match everything except 2 digits

Tags: regex

I'm having a problem with regex which matches everything except 2 digits in the middle.

**Example:**

Input : `40442**75**22123456`

Match : `75`

Allow: `4044273xxxxxxxx`, `4044255xxxx` etc..

**The expression I have is:** `[0-9]{5}[0-68-9]{1}[0-46-9]{1}[0-9]{8}`

It works for exact match but fails for exception cases.

Comment: What do you mean it fails for exception cases? Are the numbers to match predetermined or will they at least always be in the same position? What is your criteria for determining which numbers to remove?

Comment: You cannot match everything except something in the middle. You need to get the first 5, then concatenate that value with the last  8 digits? Capture both groups with `^(\d{5})\d{2}(\d{8})$` and concat them.

Comment: What regex engine are you using, and are there any modifiers you are setting on that engine?

Comment: You don't need the two `{1}` if there's only one occurence anyway. `[0-68-9]{1}` is the same as `[0-68-9]`.

Comment: If you just want to allow `75` in that spot, use an alternation.

Comment: Thanks Protectator ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to allow 75 in that spot, use an alternation.
Put all your *exceptions* in an alternation. There will be overlap,
but there will be some not allowed.
If it's a case where the ones *not allowed* are few, then use a general
range with a negative assertion, to disallow some. I.e.`[0-9]{2} (?<!52|74)`

`[0-9]{5}(?:[0-68-9][0-46-9]|75)[0-9]{8}`

Expanded

```
 [0-9]{5} 
 (?:
      [0-68-9] 
      [0-46-9] 
   |  75
   |  [0-9]5
   |  etc...
 )
 [0-9]{8}
```

Comment: it does not work for this pattern 404427422123456, it should fail as it should match everything except 75.

Comment: Here you go `[0-9]{5}(?!75)[0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}` everything except 75.

Comment: Thank you Sln, its working exactly what i was looking for.